# How to properly retrieve post body .net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to retrieve post body with ASP.NET server but it is not receiving the body.

This is my controller

```
[HttpPost]
public Boolean ReleaseProtection([FromBody]string value)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("returning value");
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(value);
    return true;
}
```

This is my client c# script

```
var credentials = new Dictionary<string, string>()
{
    {"token", Token.Value},
    {"repoId", repoId}
};

var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(credentials);
var response = await client.PostAsync(Ribbon1.DOTNETHOSTURL + "api/excel/ReleaseProtection", content);
var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

If I use the same method to `post` to nodeJS server, it receives message fine but `[FormBody] string value` returns empty string. Why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a pretty in depth answer about how to use [FromBody] with a POST: [Sending HTML Form Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/sending-html-form-data-part-1)

The short version is that you don't want to have a raw `string value`.

You should create a simple class like

```
public class MyCredentials
{
    public string Token { get; set; }
    public string RepoId { get; set; }
}
```

And then you can read it like this

```
[HttpPost]
public Boolean ReleaseProtection([FromBody]MyCredentials creds)
{
    // Do stuff...
}
```